# Update spark schema by converting to dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, dataset

I would like to update the schema of an spark dataframe by first converting it to a dataset which contains less columns. Background: i would like to remove some deeply nested fields from a schema.

I tried the following but the schema does not change:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val initial_df = spark.range(10).withColumn("foo", lit("foo!")).withColumn("bar", lit("bar!"))

case class myCaseClass(bar: String)

val reduced_ds = initial_df.as[myCaseClass]
```

The schema still includes the other fields:

```
reduced_ds.schema // StructType(StructField(id,LongType,false),StructField(foo,StringType,false),StructField(bar,StringType,false))
```

Is there a way to update the schema that way?`

It also confuses me that when i collect the dataset it only returns the fields defined in the case class:

```
reduced_ds.limit(1).collect() // Array(myCaseClass(bar!))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a fake `map` operation to force the projection using the predefined `identity` function:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val initial_df = spark.range(10).withColumn("foo", lit("foo!")).withColumn("bar", lit("bar!"))

case class myCaseClass(bar: String)

val reduced_ds = initial_df.as[myCaseClass].map(identity)
```

This yields

```
reduced_ds.schema // StructType(StructField(bar,StringType,true))
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect in my situation :)

Answer (score 0):

in the doc: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#as%5BU%5D(implicitevidence$2:org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder%5BU%5D):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5BU%5D
it says:

> Note that as[] only changes the view of the data that is passed into
> typed operations, such as map(), and does not eagerly project away any
> columns that are not present in the specified class.

To achieve what you want to do you need to

```
initial_df.select(the columns in myCaseClass).as[myCaseClass]
```

It is normal since when u collect reduced_ds it returns record of Type myCaseClass, myCaseClass has only one attribute named bar. That's not conflicting with the fact that the dataset schema is something else